# Drupal 8: Trying to read uploaded file contents

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-8

I have a FileUploadForm, with a managed_file called "file" that I'm trying to read in submitForm.

This is what I tried so far, but the code throws an error.

```
public function submitForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
  $file = $form_state->getValue('file');
  echo $file;

  $filename = $file->getFileUri();
  $handle = fopen($filename,"rb");
  $fsize = filesize($filename);
  $contents = fread($handle, $fsize);
  fclose($handle);
  drupal_set_message($contents);
}
```

In particular, I'm stuck with how to get the filename from the uploaded file.

Comment: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/228925/get-contents-of-temporary-uploaded-file

Comment: That worked, thank you. Though it should be noted that this works only with the file field type, not the managed_file.

Comment: if its a managed file, If i remember correctly, the file data in not in the `$form_state` in the forms submit function, a file id is though.